# Force reload of authorization rules.rb with declarative authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I'm trying to use declarative authorization to make dynamic authorization so I'm storing the roles and permissions in the database.

The only problem I have is that authorization rules are loaded only once.

How can I force declarative authorization to reload the rules from inside a controller action so when I set new permissions to a role it works as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are trying the same that I'm tried, I had to change the gem a little bit.

Check this commit to see what I did:

https://github.com/bishma-stornelli/declarative_authorization/commit/b508c3c008ed4b72e9fe2ec7802bfafbc6c4590b

Now I can force to reload authorization rules by calling this method:

```
Authorization::Engine.force_reload
```

It works fine.

Comment: In the latest release, this is working.  If you are using Gemfile, make sure to load the git repo as the rubygem repo has not been updated with the latest code: gem 'declarative_authorization', :git => 'https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization.git'